# What does it mean when we say a probability of a hypothesis and how to derive the formula?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am reading Solomon Kullback's information theory and statistics and find myself puzzled by how on page 17 he derives the conditional probability of a certain hypothesis conditional on the observed variable of the data

$$P\left(H_{i} \mid x\right)=\frac{P\left(H_{i}\right) f_{i}(x)}{P\left(H_{1}\right) f_{1}(x)+P\left(H_{2}\right) f_{2}(x)}[\lambda],$$

where $H_{i}, i=1,2,$ is the hypothesis that $X$ is from the statistical population with probability measure $\mu_i$. $f_i$ is defined previously as the *generalized probability density*: considering probability space $\left(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{S}, \mu_{i}\right), i=1,2$, assmes $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are *absolutely continuous* wrt one another, denoted as $\mu_{1} \equiv \mu_{2}$, let $\lambda$ be another probability measure such that $\lambda \equiv \mu_{1}, \lambda \equiv \mu_{2}$, then by Radon-Nikodym theorem there exists function $f_i(x), i =1,2$ called *generalized probability density* unique up to set of probability 0 in $\lambda$, measurable $\lambda$, $0<f_{i}(x)<\infty[\lambda], i = 1,2$ such that $$\mu_{i}(E)=\int_{E} f_{i}(x) d \lambda(x), \quad i=1,2$$ for all $E \in \mathscr{S}$. Symbol $[\lambda]$ mean statement is true except for set E such that $\lambda(E)=0$ (I don't know why we need this...)

However if we apply the Baye's theorem:

$$P\left(H_{i} \mid x\right)=\frac{P\left(x \mid H_i\right) P\left(H_{i}\right)}{\sum P\left(x \mid H_{i}\right) P\left(H_{i}\right)},$$ which need further justification to $$=\frac{f_{i}(x) P(H_{i})}{\sum f_{i}(x) P\left(H_{i}\right)}$$

I don't know how this can be achieved...  I am also having trouble understanding where $P$ is defined... Since in Kullback's book notation P is only introduced up to this point, I am not sure what space $P$ is defined upon. Because in my understanding we need to work with a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $P$ is clearly defined. Here it seems the probability space is no longer the $\left(\mathscr{X}, \mathcal{S}, \mu_{i}\right), i=1,2$ but something else... if I don't define the space clearly I don't know what event $H_1$ and $H_2$ and what kind of set they are so $P(H_1)$ and $P(H_2)$ is well-defined...

Comment: The $[\lambda]$ notation you mention relates to the measure-theoretic integral being unique only on sets that have greater than zero measure, that is to say two functions $f$ and $g$ that are equal on all sets apart from sets with zero measure, will have the same integral. Sorry if you knew this and your question was more specific

Comment: If you equate the RHS of the formula following "However if we apply the Baye's theorem" to the RHS of the first equation you will find $p(x|H_{i})=f_{i}(x)$. Again sorry if you recognised this and you had something deeper in mind.

Comment: Let $X:\Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with measure $\mu:\mathscr{R}\longrightarrow [0,1]$ then the image measurable space is $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{R})$ but there exists an underlying measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ such that $\mathbb{P}\{\omega\in\Omega:X(x)\in H\}=\mu(H)=\int_{H}f(x)\lambda(dx)$ for all $H\in\mathscr{R}$. The $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ is the subsets of $\Omega$ whilst the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{R}$ is the of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus I think your $P(H)$ means $Prob(H)=\mathbb{P}\{\omega\in\Omega:X(x)\in H\}=\mu(H)=\int_{H}f(x)\lambda(dx)$

Comment: Sorry didn't have time to amend my notation to your question in the last comment, but it seems you might have forgotten about the underlying probability space?

Comment: @dandar Hi, my problem is $P$ is a probability function, and $f$ is a propensity function, how could these two equal each other?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with propensities. After looking into this it seems rather philosophical. I think your book is referring to the bit in this blog with Bayes theorem in it (section 3.5): https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#ProInt